# How to access web project files from localhost in ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu

I was just following a simple tutorial on pgrouting **[HERE](http://workshop.pgrouting.org/chapters/installation.html#workshop)**.My question is about ubuntu through.

In the link i have posted, you will see the following 2 commands:

```
cp -R /usr/share/pgrouting/workshop ~/Desktop/pgrouting-workshop
sudo ln -s ~/Desktop/pgrouting-workshop /var/www/html/pgrouting-workshop
```

The first command works, I.E. it creates a copy on the desktop, the 2ns command is the one that does't work, it is meant to create a symbolic link , but intead i get a error when i run the above command , the error is as follows:

> ln: failed to create symbolic link ‘/var/www/html/pgrouting-workshop’:
>   No such file or directory.

So there we have it , the directory itself doesn't exists. , In the tutorial that i have linked basically after the symbolic link has been created , i can accress my folders like so,

```
http://localhost/pgrouting-workshop/web/
```

So basically my question is , what do i need to do, in order to access my folders in the above fashion ? Do i have to install XAMPP ? or just create the directory's ?

Thank you.

Alex-z.

Answer (score 0):

This is an alternate solution,

```
$ cd ~/Desktop/pgrouting-workshop
$ python -m SimpleHTTPServer 8000
```

This will start a server in port 8000 and you can access all the files by going to localhost:8000

Comment: what if i want to stop the server and close the port ?

Comment: hit Ctrl+c in terminal where the server is running.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the hints from [Symbolic Link: No such file or directory](https://askubuntu.com/questions/193670/symbolic-link-no-such-file-or-directory)

You might not execution enable for your directory. Try this:

```
chmod +x ~/Desktop/pgrouting-workshop
sudo ln -s ~/Desktop/pgrouting-workshop /var/www/html/pgrouting-workshop
```